# How to fetch addSelect query result as single entity?

Tags: php, orm, entity, symfony4, query-builder

I got

Foo entity:

```
class Foo
{
  private $name;

  /**
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Bar", mappedBy="foo", orphanRemoval=true)
    */
  private bars;
  ...
}
```

Bar entity

```
class Bar
{
  private $baz

   /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Foo", inversedBy="bars")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
  private $foo;
  ...
}
```

Foo repositiory:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('f')
            ->select('f as foo')
            ->leftJoin('f.bars', 'b')
            ->addSelect('b')
            ->addSelect('SUM(b.baz) as baz_total')
            ->having('SUM(b.baz) > 0')
            ->groupBy('f.id')
            ->orderBy('f.id', 'ASC')->getQuery()->getResult();
```

a single row the result looks like:

```
array(
  'foo' => array( // Foo Entity
      ...
      'name' => ...,
      'bars' => array(...)), //ArrayCollection 
  'baz_total' //scalar value 
)
```

and temple looks like:

```
{% for row in foos %}
  {{ row.foo.name }}
  {{ row.baz_total}}
{% endfor %}
```

Is there any way make it works like:

result:

```
array(
  'name' => ...,
  'bars' => array(...)), //ArrayCollection 
  'baz_total' // extra select as part of entity 
) ...
```

template:

```
{% for foo in foos %}
  {{ foo.name }}
  {{ foo.baz_total}}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: What do you mean "extra select as part of entity"? It's not clear what you are asking, but it might help to know how you would want to use what you are asking for.

Answer (score 0):

Change your foo repository to:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('f')
            ->select('f, b, SUM(b.baz) as baz_total')
            ->leftJoin('f.bars', 'b')
            ->having('SUM(b.baz) > 0')
            ->groupBy('f.id')
            ->orderBy('f.id', 'ASC')->getQuery()->getResult();
```

If you want the full entity, just "select" the alias. Symfony will populate the array with the entity.

That should result in your requested result. Not tested.